# SQL log file parser

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have a read log file function to get select operation from database log file like this:

```
def getSelectMySql(log):
     with open(log,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as data:
        lines   = []
        for baris in data:
            bariss      = baris.rstrip()
            newBaris    = re.sub(r'\t|\n|\r|\s{2,}',' ', bariss)
            lines.append(newBaris)
            result      = []
            buffer      = []
            success     = False
            for line in lines:
                befSelect   = re.compile(r'^.+?(?=SELECT)')
                date        = re.search(r"\b(\d{6})(?=\s\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b", line)# (\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})
                select      = re.search(r'\b(SELECT)\b',line)
                parentheses = re.compile('[(){}]')
                if date:
                    dat = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.group(), '%y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    if buffer:
                        result.append(tuple(buffer))
                        buffer.clear()
                    buffer.append(dat)
                if line.endswith("important") or line.endswith("'%general_log%'") or line.endswith("puro"):
                    success = True if line.endswith("important") else False
                else:
                    if success:
                        if select and not line.endswith("SELECT"):
                            line = re.sub(befSelect,'',line)
                            line = re.sub(parentheses,'',line)
                            buffer.append(line)
            result.append(tuple(buffer))
        print('Done\n')
        return(result)
```

from the data, this function will one save select line after `important` word. the example of file, like this:

```
190413  7:55:31 32168376 Query  SHOW variables like '%general_log%'
        32168491 Connect    puro@17#.##.#.## on puro
        32168491 Query  SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE `identifier` = 'ca28a3b30f893899556749679f8d3066' LIMIT 1
        32168491 Quit   
        32168492 Connect    important@172.2#.#.# on important
        32168492 Query  SET NAMES 'utf8'
        32168492 Query  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `sys_user`
        32168492 Query  SELECT
    kcu.constraint_name,
    kcu.column_name,
    kcu.referenced_table_name,
    kcu.referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON
    (
        kcu.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog OR
        (kcu.constraint_catalog IS NULL AND rc.constraint_catalog IS NULL)
    ) AND
    kcu.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema AND
    kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
WHERE rc.constraint_schema = database() AND kcu.table_schema = database()
AND rc.table_name = 'sys_user' AND kcu.table_name = 'sysx_user'
        32168492 Query  SELECT * FROM `lecturer_syllabus` WHERE ((`lec_id`='588') AND (`ta`='2016') AND (`sem_ta`='2')) AND (deleted !=1)
        32168492 Query  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `lect_year_syllabus`
```

The output will be like:

```
[['190413', '7:55:31', SELECT * FROM `lecturer_syllabus` WHERE ((`lec_id`='588') AND (`ta`='2016') AND (`sem_ta`='2')) AND (deleted !=1)]]
```

But as this is my first try, I need an opinion about what I've tried, because my code runs slow with larger file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Performance

Overall I believe that you are doing some things more times that you need.

- Although compiling regexes does not take much time, if you would scan a file that has 100mln lines, the compilation on single regex (multiple times) might take up to 1 minute (it takes 108 seconds on my machine) of accumulated time. You can just compile them once before all loops (or even outside the function).
- If I understand the code correctly, you are scanning each line many times. How about doing each line only once?

  ```
  lines = []
  for baris in data:
      # strip line and append to lines
  for line in lines:
      # do the rest
  ```
- In addition to above, if parse one line at a time, it will save you a lot of memory if files are *really* huge (see also point 4. below).

  ```
  def getSelectMySql(log_lines_provider): # log_lines_provider is a generator that would yield one line at a time. 
      for line in log_lines_provider:
           yield extract_line_details(line)
  ```

### Code style

Overall, I think code is not easily readable. I had to read it a few times to get a feeling of what you are trying to do.

1. `return(result)` does not need brackets.
2. I think   `else:    if success: if select and not` could be replaced by simple `elif`
3. I am not sure what `baris` means but I think it would be more readable if you renamed this variable to `line` or `log_line` to indicate that it is one line of the log file.
4. I would split the code to many functions e.g. :

   ```
   def getSelectMySql(log):
       lines = [] 
       with open(log,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as data:
           lines = get_log_lines(log) # THIS IS A BAD IDEA IF THE FILES ARE LARGE, see above
       result = []
       for line in lines: # note indent here, since you loaded all lines there is no need to keep the file open
           result.append(extract_line_details(line))
       return result
   ```
5. `success = True if line.endswith("important") else False` can be simplified to `success = line.endswith("important")`

Disclaimer: all above is just my **opinion**, please do not treat is as a single source of truth.

Comment: thank you so much for your review, `baris` mean line (on Indonesia language). In the point 2, do you mean that I replace all of it to be just a `elif` or `elif success == (select and not line.endswith("SELECT"))` ?

Comment: If I must split the function like in point 4, where should I put `buffer` list?

Answer (score 1):

To add to @MaLiN223's answer, I think adding each line to `lines` is unnecessary and leads to weird looping behavior. You'll wind up looping over earlier lines multiple times. For example:

```py
lines = []

lines.append('a')
for line in lines:
    print(line)

# a

lines.append('b')
for line in lines:
    print(line)

# a
# b
```

I'm not sure if that's the desired behavior or not, you might need to take another look at what you're trying to accomplish. I would say it's much better to keep it as a single for loop

### `str.strip()`

You are using excess memory and losing readability by creating new objects from `baris` and calling them different things. You don't use the original `baris` past the `re.sub` part, so you carry around extra objects. I would keep the name `baris`, as it's clear what it is: it's your looping variable:

```py
for baris in data:
    baris = baris.rstrip() 
    baris = re.sub(r'\t|\n|\r|\s{2,}',' ', baris)
```

### `re.compile`

The benefit of `re.compile` is you cut way down on the overhead required to re-parse your regular expression, especially in a loop:

```py
python -m timeit -s 'import re; x = "abc123"' 'for i in range(100000): re.match("\w\d", x)'
10 loops, best of 3: 64.1 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'import re; x = "abc123"; y = re.compile("\w\d")' 'for i in range(100000): y.match(x)'
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 msec per loop
```

However, by compiling *inside* a loop, you lose that benefit entirely. I would move these regular expressions:

```py
befSelect   = re.compile(r'^.+?(?=SELECT)')
date        = re.search(r"\b(\d{6})(?=\s\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b", line)
select      = re.search(r'\b(SELECT)\b',line)
parentheses = re.compile('[(){}]')
```

Up to the top, outside of your `with open` statement. This way you aren't re-compiling during every line, even if you don't need to.

So your regex should look like:

```py
def getSelectMySql(log):
    befSelect_re   = re.compile(r'^.+?(?=SELECT)')
    date_re        = re.compile(r"\b(\d{6})(?=\s\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b")
    select_re      = re.compile(r'\b(SELECT)\b')
    parentheses_re = re.compile('[(){}]')

    with open....:
        ~snip~
        for baris in data:
            ~snip~
            # compiled regex supports search, sub, find, etc.
            date = date_re.search(baris)
            select = select_re.search(baris)

            ~snip~
                baris = befSelect_re.sub('', baris)
                baris = parentheses_re.sub('', baris)
```

### Value of `success`

One of the big problems I see is that you are re-setting `success = False` during every iteration of the file handle. I would set that outside of the `for` loop:

```py
success = False
with open...
```

However, this brings up a new logical flow question. In your `if` statement:

```py
if baris.endswith("important") or baris.endswith("'%general_log%'") or baris.endswith("puro"):
    success = True if baris.endswith("important") else False
```

It seems odd to check for all of them if you are going to re-check again. I'd break this into multiple statements:

```py
if baris.endswith("important"):
    success = True
elif baris.endswith("'%general_log%'") or baris.endswith("puro"):
    success = False
else:
    # put this in one line. The ternary operator will evaluate early
    # if success is False, avoiding the rest of the boolean checks
    if success and select and not baris.endswith("SELECT"):
        ...
```

Overall, keeping things as a single loop will keep memory overhead down for large files, allow you to iterate over the lines once and only once, and keep your variables relatively easy to track:

````py
def getSelectMySql(log):
    befSelect_re   = re.compile(r'^.+?(?=SELECT)')
    date_re        = re.compile(r"\b(\d{6})(?=\s\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b")# (\d{1,}:\d{2}:\d{2})
    select_re      = re.compile(r'\b(SELECT)\b')
    parentheses_re = re.compile('[(){}]')
    spacing = re.compile(r'\t|\n|\r|\s{2,}')
    success = False

    with open(log,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as data:
        for baris in data:
            baris      = baris.rstrip()
            baris      = spacing.sub(' ', baris)
            result, buffer = [], []
            date        = date_re.search(baris)
            select      = select_re.search(baris)

            if date:
                dat = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.group(), '%y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                if buffer:
                    result.append(tuple(buffer))
                    buffer.clear()
                buffer.append(dat)
            if baris.endswith("important"):
                success = True
            elif baris.endswith("'%general_log%'") or baris.endswith("puro"):
                success = False
            else:
                # this will terminate early if success is false
                # and won't evaluate the rest of the expression
                if success and select and not baris.endswith("SELECT"):
                    baris = befSelect_re.sub('', baris)
                    baris = parentheses_re.sub('', baris)
                    buffer.append(baris)
            result.append(tuple(buffer))
        print('Done\n')
        return result
```
````